# Oracle 12c: TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, rhel7

We have a new database server on RHEL 7 and Oracle 12c. The old database server is RHEL 4 and Oracle 10g. I need to dump the data using the 12c client from the new server to the old server.

I configured the tnsnames - however, while testing `tnsping`, I'm getting `TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out`. I double-checked everything and all of the parameters look ok. I tried checking the old server firewall and it was disabled and no restrictions were in place. I tried to `tnsping` database instances to our old staging and development servers, and I get the the response in less than 10ms.

Below is the `tnsnames` entry for our old server:

```
RPROD_1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.102.139)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = RPROD.GET2HAWAII.COM)
    )
  )
```

Here are the trace files from `tnsping:

```
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlstdipi: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlstdipi: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfun2awanm: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgiinit: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nncpcin_maybe_init: default name server domain is [root]
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgiinit: Installing read path
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgsrsp: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgsrsp: Obtaining path parameter from names.directory_path or native_names.directory_path
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgsrdp: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgsrdp: Setting path:
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgsrdp: checking element TNSNAMES
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgsrdp: checking element EZCONNECT
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgsrdp: Path set
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfun2a: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlolgobj: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgrne: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgrne: Going though read path adapters
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgrne: Switching to TNSNAMES adapter
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftboot: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlpaxini: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlpaxini: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftmlf_make_local_addrfile: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftmlf_make_local_addrfile: construction of local names file failed
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftmlf_make_local_addrfile: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlpaxini: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlpaxini: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile: system names file is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/db_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftmlf_make_system_addrfile: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftboot: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftrne: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftrne: Original name: rprod_1
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfttran: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfttran: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftrne: Using tnsnames.ora address (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.102.139)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = RPROD.GET2HAWAII.COM))) for name rprod_1
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftrne: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgrne: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlolgserv: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfggav: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftgav: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftgav: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnftfrm: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfgfrm: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlolgserv: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlolgobj: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlolfmem: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nlolfmem: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfun2awanm: Getting the path of sqlnet.ora
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfun2awanm: Getting the adapter name
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] nnfun2awanm: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:179] snsgblini: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nsmal: 288 bytes at 0x1afe400
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nscall: connecting...
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nlad_pr: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nlad_pr: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nlad_pr: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nlad_aand: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nlad_ind: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nlad_ind: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nlad_aand: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nladini: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nladini: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nladget: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nladget: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nsmal: 122 bytes at 0x1b00090
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nsc2addr: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.102.139)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=RPROD.GET2HAWAII.COM)))
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttbnd2addr: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinGetAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttbnd2addr: using host IP address: 192.168.102.139
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] snlinFreeAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttbnd2addr: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nsmal: 1912 bytes at 0x1b00120
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nsmal: 3352 bytes at 0x1b008a0
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nsmal: 168 bytes at 0x1b017d0
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nsopen: opening transport...
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttcon: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttcon: toc = 1
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttcnp: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttcnp: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttcni: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttcni: Tcp conn timeout = 60000 (ms)
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttctl: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttctl: Setting connection into non-blocking mode
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] nttcni: trying to connect to socket 5.
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] ntt2err: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] ntt2err: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:26:50:180] ntctst: size of NTTEST list is 1 - not calling poll
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:240] sntpoltst: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:240] nttcni: TImeout or Error on this socket
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nttcni: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nttcon: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nserror: nsres: id=0, op=65, ns=12535, ns2=12560; nt[0]=505, nt[1]=0, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=0, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nsopen: unable to open transport
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nsvntx_dei: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nsvntx_dei: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nsmfr: 3352 bytes at 0x1b008a0
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nsmfr: 1912 bytes at 0x1b00120
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nldntUpdateNodeTable: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] snlinGetAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] snlinGetAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] snlinFreeAddrInfo: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] snlinFreeAddrInfo: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nsmfr: 122 bytes at 0x1b00090
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nscall: connecting...
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nladget: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nladget: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nsmfr: 288 bytes at 0x1afe400
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nladtrm: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nladtrm: exit
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nlse_term_audit: entry
[09-JAN-2018 20:27:50:241] nlse_term_audit: exit
```

Comment: It has to do with TCP traffic over a specific port. It could be a network timeout due to inactivity.  Test with telnet/ping to ensure the database is still active. This is a generic network issue where the other side of the connection has closed the connection. This could be happening due to firewalls, switches on the network or the actual back-end server (in this case the Oracle server).The error that you see signifies that the Oracle driver is unable to make a connection to the database, and it is timing out. This is usually a network issue.

Comment: @AnupDey checked all the network connections and I was able to ping both servers and vice-versa. The servers are in rackspace so I don't really have an idea as to how they put into network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a network issue, involving the net mask of both servers where the other server has incorrect net mask.